# Protecting QField layer from feature deletions

Tags: feature-layer, qfield

I have a polygon layer that will be shared with other users. I do not want anyone to be able to delete or modify the polygon shape. I do need them to be able to edit other feature attributes.

Is it possible to do this in QGIS?

The layer will be used in the QField app.

Comment: are you working with shapefiles? are they stored on a shared windows drive or some other shared location?

Comment: I am working with shapefiles but they are uploaded to tablet devices for field data collection.

Comment: Check the documentation - there is a concept of a 'read-only' layer that might do the trick: https://qfield.org/docs/project-management/vector-layers.html

Answer (score 1):

When using QGIS 3.12 or 3.14, you now have a lock geometries option when packaging using qfieldsync.